# MYSQL will not start

Tags: mysql

I am getting the errors below when trying to start MYSQL. 
I've deleted both the ./ib_logfile0 and ./ib_logfile1 files and still no success.  I'm assuming is has something to do with not being able to write to the temp file but I don't know the location of that directory.

```
140527 15:56:04 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140527 15:56:04 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140527 15:56:04 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140527 15:56:04 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140527 15:56:04 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/ibmZXLyt' (Errcode: 13)
140527 15:56:04  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
140527 15:56:04 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140527 15:56:04 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
/usr/sbin/mysqld: File '/var/log/mysql_slow.log' not found (Errcode: 13)
140527 15:56:04 [ERROR] Could not use /var/log/mysql_slow.log for logging (error 13). Turning logging off for the whole duration of the MySQL server process. To turn it on again: fix the cause, shutdown the MySQL server and restart it.
140527 15:56:04 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140527 15:56:04 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB That means you have an error the `my.cnf` file usually located in `/etc/mysql/`

Comment: I used my backup my.cnf file from before the problems occured, didn't work for me though.

Comment: 1. Is `/tmp` writable? 2. Isn't the disk full? (`df -h /tmp`)

Comment: That was the problem, /tmp was not writable.

Answer (score 2):

`Errcode: 13` means Access denied.  Assuming MySQL is trying to create a file in /tmp, which is 777 I guess this is incorrect configuration of either selinux or apparmor (on Debian systems).

Try to disable selinux

```
    echo 0 >/selinux/enforce
```

If it doesn't help, stop apparmor (if you run Debian or Ubuntu)

```
    # /etc/init.d/apparmor stop
    # /etc/init.d/apparmor teardown
```